# browsers fetches JSON file from cache

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am loading live map using json file but when i login the page some time it loads the json file from server n show the live map location. But sometime it not load the json file it takes the data from catche file n because of catche file i unable to show the live location. Please help me what to do

Thanks in advance

This is the code

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {     

  window.setInterval(function(){

  $.getJSON('json/<?php echo $vehicle_imei_no2;?>.json').done(function(json){  

     var lat_lng = new Array();
     var path = new google.maps.MVCArray();
     var poly = new google.maps.Polyline({ map: map, strokeColor: '#0000ff' });
     service = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
     directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();

       $.each(json, function(key, data) {
          latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng); 
            if(data.date == '<?php echo $currentDate;?>'){
              if(data.time >= '<?php echo $sessionTime; ?>'){
                  lat_lng.push(latLng);
                    }
                 }

        addMarker(latLng, map); //add new marker
             }); //each


             for (var i = 1; i < lat_lng.length; i++) {

                    var src = lat_lng[i];
                   var des = lat_lng[i + 1];
                   path.push(src);
                   poly.setPath(path);
                   service.route({
                       origin: src,
                       destination: des,
                       travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
                   }, function (result, status) {
                       if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                            directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);
                       }
                   });

                }



            });    //getjson

   }, 1000);//interval 
    });

 function addMarker(location,map) {
     marker.setPosition(location);
     marker.setIcon('assets/img/moving_bike.png');
     }

</script>
```

Comment: what exactly you are using to get the json file. is it $.getJSON()

Comment: Disable server caching headers for JSON files  in your server config file. But you are using PHP, why don't you serve the JSON in your application if the content is dynamically generated?

Comment: yes, i m using $.getJSON()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can globally disable cache using this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
});
```

or use `$.ajax({})` to load the json file and set `cache` to `false`

Answer (score 0):

While fetching the file regardless of what kind of method you are using use an old trick. Add to the file name a changing query string for example:

```
?t=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Where CURRENT_TIMESTAMP is generated timestamp.
For the browser it will be always a new file, but not for the server. So the browser won't use caching here.

Answer (score 0):

Please provide more information to your question, such as where the JSON is being requested from, the code used to request the JSON and similar..

Anyway, a neat trick with fetching resources is to append a random `query` to the request with javascript or even from a server side rendering process..

```
http://example.com/data/map.json?123
```

is not the same as:

```
http://example.com/data/map.json?098
```

and should make a new request since that data has *never* been cached.

An example using jQuery (stated in comments):

```
$.getJSON('/data/map.json?' + (new Date().getTime()), ...)
```

using the `Date` will also ensure you never request the same *random* number.

I'd suggest you try to fix the issue on the server side of things..

Comment: I am using this function $.getJSON('json/<?php echo $vehicle_imei_no1;?>.json).done(function(json){ });

Comment: so as my example states, try appending the `Date` `$.getJSON('json/<?php echo $vehicle_imei_no1;?>.json?' + (new Date().getTime())).done(function(json){ })`

Comment: i apply it but after applying date function it not load the json file not from server n not from cache

Answer (score 0):

i use both combination

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

$.getJSON('json/<?php echo $vehicle_imei_no1;?>.json?' + (new Date().getTime())).done(function(json){ });

});
```

and this works for me